# How should I retrieve an article's content from the Knowledge object?

Tags: apex, knowledge, articles, topics

I'm using the following query to retrieve the title and some other data based on the article's topic id.

```
SELECT Title, ArticleNumber, UrlName, Id, KnowledgeArticleId
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion
WHERE Language = 'en_US'
AND PublishStatus = 'Online'
AND Id in (SELECT EntityId FROM TopicAssignment WHERE TopicId = 'topicid')
```

However I would also need the content of the article. Is it possible to query that? What object or field should I use for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the KnowledgeArticleVersion object it is in the Knowledge__kav object. The field you are looking for is `ArticleBody__c`

- [Knowledge__kav - Salesforce Field Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Knowledge__kav.htm)